# NVidia RTX Voice, input a wav file instead of a microphone

Tags: nvidia, noise-reduction

I've downloaded this Ai software. I've tried it and it does a beautiful job with noise cancellation as the input should be the microphone.

[image]

My question is : How can I input a wav file instead of a microphone? Anyway to use this magical noise cancellation tool with a simple wav file ?